# Doing block matrices with array environment

Tags: matrices, line-spacing, arrays

I am used to writing block matrices using the `array` environment, when these matrices are decomposed in four blocks, controlling vertical spacing and using `\hfill`, etc.. Now I wanted to draw a matrix decomposed in nine blocks, but the vertical lines made by the `array` environment broke up. How can I fix it *without completely changing* the approach? (say, I'm not interested in solutions using `tikz`, at least for now).

Here's a MWE (done in Overleaf):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\begin{document}

\[  \left(
    \begin{array}{c|c}
      \mbox{\large $0$} &  \mbox{\large ${\rm Id}_n$} \\[.7ex] \hline \\[-1.5ex]
      \mbox{\large $-{\rm Id}_n$} & \mbox{\large $0$}\\
    \end{array}
  \right) \qquad \left(
    \begin{array}{c|c|c}  
\mbox{\large $0$} & \mbox{\large $0$} & \mbox{\large $0$} \\[.7ex] \hline \\[-1.5ex]
    \mbox{\large $0$} &  \mbox{\large $0$} &  \mbox{\large ${\rm Id}_n$} \\[.7ex] \hline \\[-1.5ex]
      \mbox{\large $0$} & \mbox{\large $-{\rm Id}_n$} & \mbox{\large $0$}\\
    \end{array}
  \right). \]
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing `\large` in every cell, do it globally for the array. Don't use `\\` after `\hline`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(
  \mbox{\large$
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{array}{c|c}
    0 & \mathrm{Id}_n \\
    \hline
    -\mathrm{Id}_n & 0 \\
    \end{array}
  $}% end of \mbox
\right)
\qquad
\left(
  \mbox{\large$
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{array}{c|c|c}  
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & \mathrm{Id}_n \\
    \hline
    0 & -\mathrm{Id}_n & 0 \\
    \end{array}
  $}% end of \mbox
\right).
\]
\end{document}
```

I removed all unnecessary packages. Don't use `utf8x` for it's been unmaintained for several years, but `utf8`. Note also that `\rm` has been deprecated for more than 20 years.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot! The package `utf8x` came in the Overleaf template I used to write the MWE, and I'm too lazy to type `\mathrm` instead of `\rm` (at least in my own notes, when I don't have to share the .tex file with other people), but I'll try to get used to it.